# How to add a button for each row in a LIstView?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I have 2d array of strings, and I display it on the screen using the following routine:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    props: { strings: Array<Object>, onPress: Function };
    render() { 
               return (
                    <View>
                        {this.props.strings.map( (string) => { return (<Text>{string}</Text>); } ) }
                    </View>);
              }
} 

render() {  
        // ..
        let DataSource =  ds.cloneWithRows(My2dArray);
        return (    
                <View>
                    <ListView 
                        dataSource={DataSource}
                        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                    />
                </View>
                ); // return
    } // render

renderRow(row: Object) {
        return (
            <MyComponent SingleRow = {row} />
        ); // return
} // rendeRow
```

Output:

[image]

I would like to have a button for each row, something like this:

[image]

But I am not sure how can I set my button in the `renderRow()` function. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap anything with `View` and split the row into blocks. I mean a left block with string and right block with your button, something like this

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() { 
    return (
      <View styles={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"}}>
           <View styles={{flex: 1, display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
             {
                 this.props.strings.map( (string) => { return (<Text>{string}</Text>); } ) 
             }
          </View>
          <View>
             <Button title="+" />
          </View>
       </View>
     );
   }
```